# How to detect key presses in C#

Tags: keypress

So I started programming today, and I want to make a small platforming stage in C#. I would like to know, how can I detect for example a left arrow key press. I can't find information that summarize my exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Action_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
     {
          // do something
     }
}
```

Edit: Under **Solution Explorer** select some Form where you want to control key press feature. With right mouse click select **View Designer**. Next, under **Properties** section click on **Events** icon. Finally, find **KeyDown** Event and press **Enter** Key, it will result with a function which will handle key presses...

[image: Instructions]

Comment: Can you please give an explanation for your solution, that would really help current and future readers.

Comment: Shall I write a comment or I have to edit my answer?

Comment: It is better to edit the answer. This way the relevant parts are in the answer and others don't need to read all comments. Thanks!